# What is the language preference in Pets?

Tags: discussion, editing

The writing of some of the words in English is different depending on whether you use the British English or US English. When we edit the questions and answers in Pets we should respect the original writing when it comes to these variations in language.

Tag names on the other hand are written using US English.

This has been [talked about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869/224542) in Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: *When we edit the questions and answers in Pets we should respect the original writing when it comes to these variations in language.* - Totally agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, at least in my experience on the Stack Exchange network, the spelling has been American (maybe in deference to our hosts). In general, though, I wouldn't edit a question or answer to change the spelling myself unless it was a part of a larger edit.

I find that the Canadians (like me) amongst us seem to be able to use either interchangeably in day-to-day activities. I don't know if that's good or bad or just leaves us a little mixed up. :D

Comment: [Shog's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873/168476) clarifies it - tags need to be US English, for consistency, otherwise don't edit purely to make things all American English. :)

Comment: That's precisely it. Whatever your spelling / grammar checker tells you is probably fine, as long as you're not creating a tag.